# Geary - can't access my outlook.de account *Connection Error*

Tags: pantheon-mail

I recently switched from Windows to Elementary so I'am relatively new to linux. That was my story now to my problem:

I want to add my outlook.de email to Geary but I always getting an annoying error and I have no idea how to fix it. Strangely it works perfectly fine with an Gmail account.

[image: The Error:]

I used the "geary --debug" command to get some more informations: http://pastebin.com/bnNeXzVV

I hope somebody can help my with this ;)

Comment: i got same problem. same trace.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting it up with Service:Other (I believe it is), then configure the mail settings manually. I had to do this to get Gmail working on it.

Under Incoming::
Make sure IMAP is selected.
Enter “imap-mail.outlook.de” for Server hostname.
Select “993” as the Port.
Make sure SSL/TLS is selected for SSL.

Under Outgoing::
Enter “smtp-mail.outlook.de” for Server hostname.
Select “587” as the Port.
Make sure STARTTLS is selected for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Servidor de IMAP: imap-mail.outlook.com
Puerto de IMAP: 993
Cifrado: SSL

Servidor de SMTP: smtp-mail.outlook.com
Puerto de SMTP: 587
Cifrado: STARTTLS